# Flask Sijax handling callbacks in @app.before_request

Tags: python, ajax, flask, sijax

I have callbacks in @app.before_request in my Flask application.

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():

  def alert(response):
    response.alert('Message')

  if g.sijax.is_sijax_request:
    g.sijax.register_callback('alert', alert)
    return g.sijax.process_request()
```

The reason I have this is because the Ajax request is present on every page in my application. This works well until I want to have a page specific callback i.e defining an AJAX request with Sijax in a view because `if g.sijax.is_sijax_request:` is used twice so I cannot register the callbacks that are specific to a view.

Is there a workaround for this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register your default callback in the after_request event and check if the `_callback` dictionary is empty, if so, register the default callback else pass on the existing response.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, g, render_template_string
import flask_sijax

path = os.path.join('.', os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static/js/sijax/')

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SIJAX_STATIC_PATH'] = path
app.config['SIJAX_JSON_URI'] = '/static/js/sijax/json2.js'

flask_sijax.Sijax(app)


@app.after_request
def after_request(response):

    def alert(obj_response):
        print 'Message from standard callback'
        obj_response.alert('Message from standard callback')

    if g.sijax.is_sijax_request:
        if not g.sijax._sijax._callbacks:
            g.sijax.register_callback('alert', alert)
            return g.sijax.process_request()
        else:
            return response
    else:
        return response

_index_html = '''
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/sijax/sijax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> {{ g.sijax.get_js()|safe }}</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="javascript://" onclick="Sijax.request('alert');">Click here</a>
</body>
</html>
'''

_hello_html = '''
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/sijax/sijax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> {{ g.sijax.get_js()|safe }}</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="javascript://" onclick="Sijax.request('say_hi');">Click here</a>
</body>
</html>
'''


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string(_index_html)


@flask_sijax.route(app, '/hello')
def hello():
    def say_hi(obj_response):
        print 'Message from hello callback'
        obj_response.alert('Hi there from hello callback!')

    if g.sijax.is_sijax_request:
        g.sijax._sijax._callbacks = {}
        g.sijax.register_callback('say_hi', say_hi)
        return g.sijax.process_request()

    return render_template_string(_hello_html)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=7777, debug=True)
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly, except all callbacks registered are executed twice since if `g.sijax.is_sijax_request: ... return g.sijax.process_request()` is used twice. Is there a way to get around this issue?

Comment: Thanks, I just implemented your code, the callbacks in views work. However when using callbacks that are in `@app.after_request` when there are also callbacks in the view that is requested, they do not work.

Comment: Register the global callbacks in your specific pages callback registration too.

Comment: I cannot do that since my Flask application is setup using blueprints, so my global callbacks are in `__init__.py` and my view specific ones are in another file

Comment: The code for the callbacks could be in a separate module that's accessible by both your app `__init__.py` and your blueprints.